# Document concurrent update

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a document like:

```
{
  owner: 'alex',
  live:  'some guid'
}
```

Two or more users can update live field simultaneously.

How can I make sure that only the first user wins and others updates fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the semantics you want if you store some variable like "times_updated" in the document. Operations on a single document are atomic, so you can check that the field is the value you expect, and then throw an error if it isn't.

It might look something like:

```
var timesUpdated = 3

r.table('foo').get(rowId).update(function(row) {
     return r.branch(row('timesUpdated').eq(timesUpdated),
          {
              timesUpdated: row('timesUpdated').add(1),
              live: 'some special value'
          },
          r.error('Someone else updated the live field!')
     );
}, {returnChanges: true})
```

So if another query comes in before you for `timesUpdated = 3`, your query will blow up. When do you get `timesUpdated`? That depends on how your app is designed, and what you're trying to do.

Another thing to note is that adding `{returnChanges: true}` is really useful because it allows you to get the new value of `timesUpdated` atomically. You can also see what exactly changed in the updated document.